# Why my javascript execute just the first lines ? Prestashop

Tags: javascript, css, prestashop

I am building a website with the CMS Prestashop,and I am trying to change its style.
In prestashop we can add one javascript file and do some change, however the system executes just the first lines.So the question is, why ?

Maybe its comes from my code.

```js
window.onscroll = function () {
    var title = document.getElementById('header_menu');
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
        title.classList.add("white_menu");
    } else {
        title.classList.remove("white_menu");
    }
};

var title_cat = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByClassName( 'h1' )[0];
title_cat.classList.add("font_size_null");

var research_bar= document.getElementById('_desktop_search');
research_bar.classList.add("research");
```

When i try to change the order of my lines just the first change is implemented.

Thanks in advance,
Malaury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the getElementById method is available only on DOMDocument objects (in a browser, the document).
You are trying to access the DOMDocument of an element of the DOM, which is not possible to do. (you cannot "chain" multiple *getElementById()*)

To select all h1 elements that are childrens of an element with the "main id", we could use something like:

```
var title_cat = document.querySelectorAll("#main h1");
```

or if we are only interested in the first match (like in your example):

```
var title_cat = document.querySelector("#main h1");
```